# Android GPS using old locations

Tags: android, gps

Im trying to learn more about location services in android and am attempting to build an app which can locate an Android device and send it's latitude and longitude to a server. I've had everything working as expected for a while, but am still being bothered by a small bug. When I send the command from the server to locate the device the first time, the device returns a recent, but old, location such as a road I drove on the same day.

On the second time the device receives a command from the server to locate the device, the device returns an accurate location.

Here is the relevant code:

```
LocationTracker.java
public class LocationTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {



    //flag for GPS Status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    //flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    boolean canGetLocation = false;
    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    //The minimum distance to change updates in metters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10*1000; //10,000 meters

    //The minimum time beetwen updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 10000; // 10,000 minutes

    //Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;



    public void fetchLocation(Context context) {
        getLocation(context);
        if (canGetLocation())
        {
            String stringLatitude = String.valueOf(latitude);
            String stringLongitude = String.valueOf(longitude);
            Log.i("Location: ", stringLatitude + " " + stringLongitude);
            new MyAsyncTask().execute(stringLatitude, stringLongitude);     
        }
        else
        {
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            Log.i("Error: ", "Cannot get location");
        }
    }


    public Location getLocation(Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            //getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            //getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
            {
                // no network provider is enabled
            }
            else
            {
                this.canGetLocation = true;



                //if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled)
                {
                    if (location == null)
                    {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

                        if (locationManager != null)
                        {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            updateGPSCoordinates();
                        }
                    }
                }

                //If no GPS, get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled && !isGPSEnabled)
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    Log.d("Network", "Network");

                    if (locationManager != null)
                    {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        updateGPSCoordinates();
                    }
                }                


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error : Location", "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
        }

        return location;
    }

    public void updateGPSCoordinates()
    {
        if (location != null)
        {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     */

    public void stopUsingGPS()
    {
        if (locationManager != null)
        {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(LocationTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     */
    public double getLatitude()
    {
        if (location != null)
        {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     */
    public double getLongitude()
    {
        if (location != null)
        {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     */
    public boolean canGetLocation()
    {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {   
        double newLat = location.getLatitude();
        double newLong = location.getLongitude(); 
        String stringNewLatitude = String.valueOf(newLat);
        String stringNewLongitude = String.valueOf(newLong);
        Log.i("New Location: ", stringNewLatitude + " " + stringNewLongitude);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(stringNewLatitude, stringNewLongitude);   
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
    {   
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
    {   

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
    {   
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Why is my location updating as an old location the first time it tries, and a correct location on the second time?

Also note that I would also like to remove requestLocationUpdates seen here:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

because it causes a handler on dead thread warning, but when I removed it my device stopped acquiring my location. This may be part of the problem.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using `getLastKnownLocation()`.

`location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);`

[getLastKnownLocation(String Provider)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) :
Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location fix obtained from the given provider.

This can be done without starting the provider. Note that this location could be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned off and moved to another location.